# Kernel security settings

Tags: kernel, security

What is the right security setting for the `net.ipv4.conf.all.secure_redirects` option in `sysctl.conf`?
[Here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ImprovedNetworking/KernelSecuritySettings) it sets to `1` and [Here](http://joshrendek.com/2013/01/securing-ubuntu/) sets to `0`.
Is `net.ipv4.conf.default.secure_redirects` related to previous? and ٌWhat is the right setting for it?

====

1st link (wiki.ubuntu.com) stated:

> The following sysctl settings are default at the time of this writing.
>   We intend that they stay this way.
>
> ```
> net.ipv4.conf.all.secure_redirects = 1.
> ```
>
> Prevents hijacking of routing path by only allowing redirects from gateways known in our
>   routing table.

2nd link (joshrendek.com) states:

```
# Make sure no one can alter the routing tables 
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.secure_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.secure_redirects = 0
```

Comment: Interesting question. Though there is a slight difference in wording regarding the 2 settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking at this I used Fedora as a [reference](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Community_Services_Infrastructure/1/html/Security_Policy/HostGeneralSecurity-Standard-Sysctl.html) (to see how another OS looks at this) (edit: these are Fedora's thoughts on setting up a SERVER! See the bottom part for why this is important):

[image]

---

[Documentation](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?id=v3.10#n784):

```
accept_redirects - BOOLEAN
    Accept ICMP redirect messages.
    accept_redirects for the interface will be enabled if:
    - both conf/{all,interface}/accept_redirects are TRUE in the case
      forwarding for the interface is enabled
    or
    - at least one of conf/{all,interface}/accept_redirects is TRUE in the
      case forwarding for the interface is disabled
    accept_redirects for the interface will be disabled otherwise
    default TRUE (host)
        FALSE (router)
```

---

[Here is an interesting blog](https://www.agwa.name/blog/post/icmp_redirect_attacks_in_the_wild). Conclusion:

> This arcane logic means that for a non-router (i.e. most servers), not only must `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/accept_redirects` be 0, but so must `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/interface/accept_redirects`.

---

So ...

- if you are using your system as a server set it to 0.
- if you are using your system as a desktop you can leave it on 1 (but can set it to 0 if you want to harden your system).

Both can be considered correct (and sane).